# Ошибка при создании индекса в PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Пытаюсь в phppgAdmin создать индекс

```
CREATE INDEX ON board ((lower(name)));
```

И выскакивает ошибка:

Ошибка SQL:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CREATE"
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM (CREATE INDEX ON board ((lower...
                                       ^
В операторе:
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM (CREATE INDEX ON board ((lower(name)))) AS sub
```

Как можно поправить данное недоразумение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь любым другим клиентом, который не будет пытаться делать что-то странное вместо того запроса который просите вы. Например, штатный `psql`

Это проблема именно используемого клиента, который пытается видоизменить запрос, который вы просите выполнить. Возможно, где в интерфейсе этого клиента есть режим для ввода именно команд SQL.

Comment: судя из описания https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-commands.html он должен выполнять подобные команды.

Comment: Не путайте пожалуйста СУБД postgresql, для которой ваш create index полностью адекватен и выполняющий непонятные манипуляции сторонний клиент - как вы сами написали, вы используете phppgAdmin. Вот это вот странное нечто с select count - это самовольство используемого клиента и это не является синтаксически допустимой штукой для postgresql.

Comment: значит выполнять подобные запросы можно только через консоль?

Comment: Подойдёт любой клиент, повторюсь, "который не будет пытаться делать что-то странное вместо того запроса который просите вы"

Comment: да уже через консоль выполнил нужные мне запросы.